# I get the "unable to locate package" message when trying to install php-xml-rss, even though I have the universe repo added

Tags: server, php, nginx, wordpress

I'm currently configuring a Wordpress hosting platform, and one of the packages that I need to install is `php-xml-rss`.  It's in the universe repo, which I have added, and I ran `apt-get update` and `upgrade`, so I know it's up to date.  When I run the command to download `php-xml-rss`, I just get a "unable to locate package" message.  I was able to get the rest of my packages with no issues.  Any clue what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my research I found that `php-xml-rss` package is only available in `trusty (14.04LTS)`, you can verify it [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php-xml).

A solution could be to download the .DEB files from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-xml-rss) or [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/php-xml-rss/1.0.2-3), depending on which version of Ubuntu you're using.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.  That's too bad, because I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 so I'll probably have to restart from scratch with 14.04

Comment: You can download the .DEB files and install them using `sudo dpkg -i <package>`

Comment: I might be missing something since I'm fairly new to ubuntu and to Linux in general, but when I run `sudo dpkg -i` after downloading the package, it says `<package> is not a debian format archive>.  However it says .deb on the download page.  If it helps at all I can't use a GUI for this project.